# Loading FASTA file in R faster than when using read.fasta() from seqinr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, fasta

I am currently using the function `read.fasta()` from the R package seqinr.
I think that creating an index file already make the reading faster but I was wondering if there was already another function to load it faster ?

I looked for the function `read.big.fasta()` from PopGenome, but the package has been removed from CRAN and Bioconductor, so I am not so sure about it anymore.
Any advices?

Comment: how big is your fasta? You tried readDNAStringSet from Biostrings?

Comment: @StupidWolf feel free to write the answer.

Comment: No problem, so you used read.big.fasta() in the end?

Comment: And actually what do you need to do with it? I ask because indexing does not help you to read the file fast, but enables you to retrieve sequences very quickly.

Comment: @StupidWolf  yes I used `read.big.fasta()`.  
I think my answer would go beyond the scope of my question: I have a set of probes  supposed to match specific sequences, and I am checking through the FASTA of a genome assembly file where these probes could hybridize on it.
This operation is also time consuming, with reasons.

Comment: Ok I see. Yeah then you needa read in the whole fasta. What you can do however, is the save the object and load it, for subsequent uses. I cannot install popgenome for read.big.fasta(), it was retracted from cran for some reason.

Comment: @StupidWolf yeah removed from both CRAN and Bioconductor...
I guess one way to save it would be in as .RDS file to reload it faster if it is what you meant.
Would you mind upvoting my question ? I guess the original title wasn't precise enough so it got down voted... I changed it.

Comment: Yup. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `readDNAStringSet` from `Biostrings`.

Get the human genome:
    download.file("https://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.fa.gz","../Downloads/test.fa.gz")

Using `readDNAStringSet` or `read.fasta` :

```
f1 = function(){readDNAStringSet("../Downloads/test.fa.gz")}
f2 = function(){read.fasta("../Downloads/test.fa.gz")}

library(Biostrings)
library(seqinr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(),times=5)
Unit: seconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 f1() 42.82203 43.57036 45.10369 45.64206 46.37412 47.10987     5

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(),times=5)
### did not finish running
### so definitely not the option for large fasta files
```

Comment: Yeah I mean for the technology the probes are coming from the matching assembly is hg19, but this a detail.  
I had also similar results for the benchmarking thanks for showing it in the answer !    
For the records, `read.fasta()` was around 4 times slower.